# Bluemix Ruby app health check configuration

Tags: ruby, ibm-cloud

We have a Sinatra app that is deployed to Bluemix through the Bluemix Ruby service.

However, the app is made unavailable after a while, and we suspect that the Bluemix health check is failing. We can see that there is periodic calls to the root (i.e the / route) from something we think is the Bluemix load balancer. However, our root route is protected with basic authentication.

How can we change the route that the load balancer calls for our application?

Is there any documentation for the health check feature?

Comment: Any logs? See this link for Ruby logging:
https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/troubleshoot/debugging.html#debug_runtime

Comment: Nothing interesting in the logs; it stops logging http-request attempts, so we're uncertain if traffic actually hits the app or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't appear to be possible yet. [This recently updated documentation](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/manageapps/depapps.html#deployingapps) states, under "Staging an application", that:

`To validate the app health, Diego supports the same PORT-based checks that were used for DEA. However, Diego is also designed to be able to have more generic options like URL-based health checks, which might be enabled in the future.`

It also appears that the old [DEA architecture](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/architecture/execution-agent.html#health-checks) didn't support url health checks either.

Comment: Small edit, it seems like this is available to be edited. If you add:
    health-check-type: http
    health-check-http-endpoint: /<route>
then Bluemix will use the given route in its http health checks. The default health check (if you don't set anything) is a TCP port check. I don't know how recommended it is to use this for production since it doesn't seem to be documented yet.